# Optimised way of storing threaded converstations?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

We are to design a architecture storing conversations (one to many)...

we are using the following tables (and columns)

1. messages_table - message_id, sender_id (user_id), timestamp, reference_id
2. recipients - message_id, recipient_id (user_id)
3. unread_status_table - message_id, user_id

we are storing messages in messages table, and reference_id stores the message id of starting thread.

unread status table saves only messages that are unread.

I am not sure if we should use a separate table for unread messages, advantage is, if all the messages are read, the table is empty.

please help me :)

Comment: How is an empty table an advantage? What's wrong with a "status" flag on the recipients table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one single answer to a question like this.  It all depends on how many users, how many conversations, the hardware you have, requirements for how responsive the system should be to users, and so forth.  If you can get adequate performance by not having a second table for unread messages, then that's probably the better route.  Always simplify when possible.

My thought is that, if I had a second table, it probably wouldn't be for unread messages.  Instead, in a very high-concurrency situation, that table would have no indexes apart from a primary key, and new messages would be pushed into it.  It should allow for very fast operations even when lots of new messages come in.  Then a job could run periodically to read a small number of records and push them into the main table, where the operation is slower, and then delete them from the second table.  This means that users can continue to create new messages and the system stays responsive, but it might be a little while until recipients see the messages.

But again, this approach is needed only when you have seen that performance requires it.